# better way of interaction between a web application and web service

Tags: java, web-services, soap

There is a web application and a server. These two communicates with each other using third party. Now, it is for sure that server and third party will communicate with each other using web service(SOAP). That means this third party has to be exposed as a web service.

The problem is how do the third party and web application communicate with each other? Its a two way communication. Web Application transfers the events generated by the end User to third party and third party transfers the events to web application received from server.

Other Question is whether third party should be developed as an independent web service or it should reside inside web application and for doing this I have to integrate web application into web service. Is it a good idea?

For communication between Web Application and third party, I am thinking of doing this with TCP connection. Is there any other way around?
Can anyone please suggest how can i make these entities communicating with each other?

Comment: Your question is far too broad... Why should a third party app reside inside your own application? What are the alternatives to TCP(/IP)? Please describe your use case!

Comment: Since your question is tagged with "java" I assume you want to know how to do this in Java.  If you are asking about how to write the client, use `wsimport` to generate classes from the WSDL.  If you are asking about how to write the server, use [`Endpoint.create`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Endpoint.html#create%28java.lang.Object%29) followed by `Endpoint.publish`.